# Scroll View does not update dynamically when adding new objects

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui

I have a TikTok like app that I am creating using SwiftUI. Initially, I would fetch all my videos from a database and load them into A UIScrollView using UIViewRepresentable. However, that isn't a viable solution because it takes a long time to load videos. So my plan is to load the first 4 videos, and to load the next 4 every time the user scrolls past two videos. So on startup, once I scroll to the next video, it should load the next four videos from the database.

The problem is that when I load new videos from the database, it seems that my scroll view doesn't update completely dynamicaly [Bug Example](https://vimeo.com/688709926) <- Please ignore loading speeds and buffers.

This is my scroll view code:

```
struct PlayerScrollView : UIViewRepresentable {

@Binding var data : [HomeReel]
@Binding var currentTab: Int
@Binding var toggleVideo: Bool
@Binding var segueToSearch: Bool
@Binding var currentReelIndex: Int
@Binding var reelToggle: ToggleType


func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UIScrollView{
    
    let view = UIScrollView()
    
    let childView = UIHostingController(rootView: PlayerView(data: self.$data, currentReelIndex: $currentReelIndex, currentTab: $currentTab, toggleVideo: $toggleVideo, reelToggle: $reelToggle, segueToSearch: $segueToSearch))
    
    // each children occupies one full screen so height = count * height of screen...
    
    childView.view.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: UIScreen.main.bounds.height * CGFloat((data.count)))
    
    // same here...
    
    view.contentSize = CGSize(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: UIScreen.main.bounds.height * CGFloat((data.count)))
    
    view.addSubview(childView.view)
    view.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = false
    view.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = false
    
    // to ignore safe area...
    view.contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior = .never
    view.isPagingEnabled = true
    view.delegate = context.coordinator
    
    return view
}

func updateUIView(_ uiView: UIScrollView, context: Context) {
    
    // to dynamically update height based on data...
    
    uiView.contentSize = CGSize(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: UIScreen.main.bounds.height * CGFloat((data.count)))
    for i in 0..<uiView.subviews.count{

        uiView.subviews[i].frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0,width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: UIScreen.main.bounds.height * CGFloat((data.count)))
    }
}


}
```

I use state card and environment object managers for the data passed into the player scroll view. This is how I use the PlayerScrollView:

```
 ZStack{

 PlayerScrollView(data: $homeVideosManager.reels, currentTab: $currentTab, toggleVideo: $toggleVideo, segueToSearch: $segueToSearch, currentReelIndex: $currentReelIndex, reelToggle: $reelToggle)

    }
    .onChange(of: currentReelIndex, perform: { i in
        
        //Fetching next videos
        
        if i != 0 && ((i+1) % 2 == 0) && i > lastLoadIndex{
            homeVideosManager.getNextReels(filter: reelToggle)
            lastLoadIndex = i
        }
        
    })
```

**How can I stop this white screen from appearing and load videos into my scroll view smoothly?**

Comment: I think you need to update scroll view content size when you load new videos

Comment: This would be significantly easier to help debug with a [mre]

Comment: @PratikPrajapati I tried that and the bug still appears. I actually noticed that the updateUIView was being called when new videos were being loaded without making any changes to the actual scrollView.

Comment: Do you call updateview on main thread ? Are you using state var or objects ? There is not enough information in what you show.

Comment: @PtitXav You can see my updateUiView method. I do not specify for it to happen on the main thread.